# Kendo Grid Callback function after sortable event fire

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using Kendo Grid  to  sorting table data. I want an event which fire after sorting is completed. i want like below code.

```
$("#innergrid").kendoGrid({
      sortable: true,
      Aftersorting : function(event) { alert('sorting is done') }
});
```

Comment: I think the only event that is fired when a sort happens is the databound event.  http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/documentation/api/web/grid#events-dataBound

Comment: Thank you Robin, databound event can fire event after sorting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the change event of the dataSource (will be created automatically when you init the grid). Check this: http://jsbin.com/buten/1/edit

Comment: Thank you its working usefull to. i have also used "databound" event it also works same as change event.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure is there any event which can be triggered after sorting but you can do this

********************Grid************************

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<>()
.Name("CompanyServicesGrid")
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                    .Ajax()
                    .PageSize(20)
                    .Events(events => e.RequestEnd("onRequestEnd")) 
)
```

**************************Javascript********************

```
 function onRequestEnd(e)
 { 
    if (e.type == "read"){
        if(e.sender_sort=="ColumnName")
        alert("sorting is done")
     }

  }
```

have a look at this as well

- [onRequestEnd-Link](http://www.telerik.com/forums/kendo-mvc-grid---refresh-after-ajax-row-operation)
  [OnComplete-Link](http://www.telerik.com/forums/refresh-grid-after-datasource-sync)

Comment: I am not using datasource. i have simple outer tables and inner tables. i want apply kendo grid on both (outer table and inner table). out table grid sorting works but inner table sorting using kendo gird is not working.

Comment: You always have a dataSource. If you do not see it just try to bind to the event like so

$('#gridName').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.bind('requestEnd', function () {...});